# Why is the root handler breaking the location declaration in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Why is my root handler overriding my subpath location in nginx?

I have 2 levels that I am working with in nginx: `/***` and `/core/`

I would like the following to occur:

1. When someone calls `/fun/` - proxy_pass to a different server
2. When someone calls `/notfun/` - proxy_pass to a different server
3. When someone calls `/core/` - return index.html
4. When someone calls `/core/file.html` - and there IS a file - return the file
5. When someone calls `/core/thing/` - and there IS NOT file - return index.html

It should not be possible to generate a 404 if someone is calling `/core/****`

My location declarations is as follows:

```
    location / {
      set $a_url nginx.router;
      proxy_pass https://$a_url;
    }

    location /core/ {
      alias /app/;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

How come when I add the `location /` declaration, requirements 5 breaks?

```
[17/Dec/2020:23:37:16 +0000] "GET /core/aaaa HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.64.0"
```

Comment: Was this previously working? Please show the previous working configuration.

Comment: Please share the output of `nginx -T`.

Comment: If `index.html` is located in `/app/`, the last element of `try_files` should be `/core/index.html`. You should also be aware that `try_files` and `alias` [can cause strange issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).